# Display all taxonomy based on post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I just want to display a taxonomy term based on post type so that I can display and filter the items based on their taxonomy.

My code below displays EVERY taxonomy. I want it to be only a specific post type **Publication**

```
<?php
     $taxonomy = 'articletype';

     $tax_terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, array(
        'post_type' => 'publication'
     ) );

 ?>
 <?php
     foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
         ?>
     <button class="button" data-filter=".<?php echo $tax_term->slug;?>" >
         <?php echo $tax_term->name;?>
     </button>
 <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using **Codex Function Reference/get object taxonomies**.

***Usage:***

```
<?php get_object_taxonomies( $object, $output ); ?>
```

***Parameters:***

*$object:* (array|string|object) (required):
Name of the post type, or a post object (row from posts).

*$output:* (string) (optional): The type of output to return, either taxonomy 'names' or 'objects'.

***Return Values:***

(array): All taxonomy names or objects for the given post type/post object.

also you can visit the original [codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_object_taxonomies) to get examples and more info.

Comment: I didn't know there's a function like this! I'll try this when I get back to the office. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's still doable in your case (depends on if your site is still on dev or has too much content already), but I think it would be better to create custom taxonomy for your custom post type, it would make it easier for you to orgaanize your content.

I tried to look for a function in the wp codex that sorts taxonomy by post type but I couldn't find it.

Comment: I never thought about that! I was pulling my hair yesterday looking for a function when your solution is a much better and easier one. I think I got lazy creating taxonomy for each post type so thanks!