# WP: how to get all taxonomies' name of a spcific custom type

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get all taxonomy names of a speicific custom type.
In the stackoverflow archive I found the script below for a single postID. 
I would like to loop all taxonomy names of a single custom post type and not just one with the id.
Taxomy should be: **my_tax** and the custom post type: **my_team**

```
            $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'my_tax' );
            foreach($terms as $term) {
                echo $term->name;
            }
```

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/

Comment: Refer this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36204483/5965558)

Answer (score 0):

Such code can be:

```
$type = 'my_team';
$args = array(
  'post_type' => $type,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
);

$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($my_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) {
        $post = $my_query->the_post();
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'my_tax' );
        foreach($terms as $term) {
            echo $term->name;
        }
    }
}
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the example. Unfortunately it loops only one taxonomy.